# How to use vba to click link in IE with no href,onclick?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

```
Sub sales_ann()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "http://data.eastmoney.com/bbsj/201603/yjyg.html"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    For Each ele In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")

    Debug.Print ele.textContent

     y = 2
     For i = 0 To 49
     Sheets("sale_ann").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(i).Children(0).textContent
     Sheets("sale_ann").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(i).Children(1).textContent
     Sheets("sale_ann").Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(i).Children(2).textContent
     Sheets("sale_ann").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(i).Children(3).textContent
     Sheets("sale_ann").Range("E" & y).Value = ele.Children(i).Children(4).textContent

     y = y + 1
     Next i

Next

objIE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

step 1:

```
<li class="at2" data="0">业绩预告<i></i></li>
<li data="1" class="">业绩预增<i></i></li>
<li data="2" class="">业绩预减<i></i></li>
<li data="3" id="fpygTab" class="">分配预告<i></i></li>
```

step 2:

```
<span class="clickspan">业绩变动幅度</span>
```

what i want to do is click the button "data="1"" which generated by javascript
and then click "class="clickspan"" before i scrape data in "tbody".
I have tried `execScript` and `getElementsByClassName("").click()`, but it did not work.Someone tell me to use document.querySelector() and dispatchEvent(clickEvent) but did not work too.what should i do?

Comment: Please post in English if it all possible and please include more clear details that clearly state the question.

Comment: Read this once... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Three down votes?? This question is specific and legit. Those Chinese characters are irrelevant!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably with [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

```js
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true
});
document.querySelector('li[data="1"]').dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
document.querySelector('span.clickspan').dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but it can't work in my code.Can you go specifically?

Comment: Sorry, your question was written very differently when I answered it. I don't know how to answer your question as it is phrased now.